# How to rewrite part of the URL and then attach the remaining?

Tags: url, iis, url-rewriting, redirect

For example, rewrite from www.example.com/**foo**/123  to  www.example.com/**bar**/123

In web.config I have something like:

```
<rewriteMap name="TestRM">
<add key="/foo/" value="/bar" />
</rewriteMap>

<rule name="TEST" stopProcessing="true">
<match url=".*" />
<conditions>
<add input="{TestRM:{PATH_INFO}}" pattern="(.+)" />
</conditions>
<action type="Redirect" url="http://www.example.com{C:1}" appendQueryString="false" redirectType="Temporary" />
</rule>
```

With this is place, www.example.com/foo can be redirected to www.example.com/bar, but no www.example.com/foo/123 to www.example.com/bar/123

Anything I need to add to make the last part attached?

Answer (score 0):

One of the strategy you can use is to use regex and separate the URL Parts.

For example URL:  www.example.com/foo/123

Regex: ^(/foo)(/.*)? will separate out /foo and /123  or /123/3434/ or anything after /foo

Then you can craft the redirect URL as Such:

{HTTP-HOST}/bar{R:2}